# Composed texture

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying ti make a sprite with texture, but sprite's size I don't know. As I know, I can initialize a sprite with frame with custom rect:

```
CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrame alloc] initWithTextureFilename:@"name.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
sprite = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithSpriteFrame:frame];
```

If size of texture chould be bigger, then image's size, I need to put this image (or part of it) side-to-side with first one. **How can I do this?**

Comment: mmm... maybe i don't understand correctly, what do you want to do,  but spriteframe is just a pointer to the texture in memory with needed rect of this texture. if your file, that will be loaded as texture, contains several pictures, for example, 5x10 and another one 5x10 pixels, you will get spriteframe with both of them, using CGRect(0, 0, 10, 10)

Comment: Tnx for response. You right. So, how can I clone several pictures from my texture, located in rect (100,100, 10,5), for example, in single sprite?

Comment: You may want to look at TexturePacker or Zwoptex. This sounds an awful lot like doing the manual way where tools can spare you all these headaches.

Comment: i don't think, that you can do texture tiling without opengl. so google will provide a couple of articles about it. about zwoptex - it is really cool tool, but it will not do the trick in your case.

Comment: I allready found https://github.com/asinesio/cocos2d-PRKit - this kit, but it gives me an error. tryong to solve it now.

Comment: Problem solved, see my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution.
There is a open-source kit for draw CCNode/CCSprite with any shape and fill it with any texture: [PRKit](https://github.com/asinesio/cocos2d-PRKit). But it isn't work with cocos2d v2.0. To solve this, replace `draw` method in PRFilledPolygon.m with thi one:

```
-(void) draw {
    ccGLBindTexture2D( [self.texture name] );

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    ccGLEnableVertexAttribs( kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position | kCCVertexAttribFlag_TexCoords );

    [prog use];
    [prog setUniformForModelViewProjectionMatrix];

    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(CGPoint), areaTrianglePoints);
    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(CGPoint), textureCoordinates);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, areaTrianglePointCount);
}
```

And `prog (CCGLProgram *)` is defined in `initWithPoints:andTexture:usingTriangulator:`

```
prog = [[CCShaderCache sharedShaderCache] programForKey:kCCShader_PositionTexture];
```

---

Also, if you work with Box2D, to make this PRFilledPolygon compatible with b2Body, do the following (this is lazy method. I suggest you follow OOP and do this right and beatiful):

1. Subclass PRFilledPolygon from CCSprite (it is CCNode, by default)
2. Make a clone of PhysicsSprite, generated by template of box2d, and subclass it from PRFilledPolygon (it's CCSprite, by default)
3. When you initing your body, use ths new class insteed of PhysicsSprite, just like you did it before.